# 4 devices on 1 Apple ID no have problems

Tags: ios, messages, apple-id

We have 2 iPad minis and 2 iPhones on the same Apple ID when I text my husband it goes to all 4 devices including mine twice. When anyone messages from the other 3 devices it goes to all 4 including my phone twice. When anyone tries to FaceTime  any of our devices it goes to all 4 devices. How can we get it to only go to one device ( the one we are sending the message to)?

Answer (score 2):

**Use different Apple IDs on each device.** Using the same Apple ID will mean that the devices will be indistinguishable to FaceTime/iMessage/etc.

Comment: not for each Device - Use different `Apple IDs` / `iCloud Accounts` for every Person??

Comment: @bMalum They're synonymous—doing one does the other.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned, you should use a different Apple ID on each device, for Messaging.

However, for the *Store*, you can use the same ID across devices to allow you to share apps, music and other purchased content.

Answer (score 0):

**iCloud Accounts** are **Personal**, so this means, every Apple User *should* have an **own** iCloud Account.

You can use your *iCloud Accounr* for the *Store* and *iCloud Services* and your husband can use it also in the Store.

(Best way is to add first the new iCloud Account on your husbands Phone - switch to AppStore App - logout from iCloud Account - login with AppleID with Payment or purchased Apps)

In the Future you can set up a Family Account (iOS 8 Feature) so it will be no Problem to share purchased Apps and Games with the *Personal iCloud Account* of you Husband.